# Add event to database on user click in Meteor

Tags: hyperlink, meteor

I am trying to update an collection in Meteor when a user clicks on a certain link.  The link opens up a new tab, which is on an external site.  However, I want to store this click in my database.

I have tried using e.preventDefault(), but then I can't get the link to open in a new tab.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a click event and use a `window.location` after inserting into the database.
So, it would look something like this:

```
Template.name.events({
  'click a' : function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Insert data into database
    Table.insert({
      // data here
    });
    // Open new tab
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }
});
```

Comment: this works, but window.open results in the popup blocker for chrome coming up.  any way to get around that?

Comment: and it also does not work in Safari as well.  I read on another question that window.open does not work well cross-browser.  Is there any way to do the data insertion after the user leaves the page, as some sort of simultaneous background job.

Answer (score 1):

You ought not to use javascript to open the new tab since this will activate the popup blocker. The best solution is to have a link, as normal, and track the link on the side:

Html:

```
<template name="link">
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" id="the_link">CLick</a>
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.link.events({
    'click a#the_link': function(e,tmpl) {
        MyCollection.update({_id: "the_link_id"} , {$inc { "clicks":1 } });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the insertion in the server side which is secure. The window can be opened in the success of the response.

In Client

```
Template.name.events{(
 "click .clickevent":function(e){

   e.preventDefault();
       Meteor.call("Methodname", datatoinsert,function(err){
       if(!err)
        window.open(url, '_blank');                
      })   
       }    

  )};
```

In Server

```
Meteor.methods({
Methodname:function(datatoinsert){

  Tablename.insert({
  //insert data here
   })    
  }
 });
```

In this way you can add event and on successful data insert you can open a window.

I hope it helps you.